# 16 bit assembly sending character to serial port

Tags: assembly, x86, serial-port, masm

I created bridge on virtual serial ports(COM7 & COM8) with hdd device monitor studio and want to send and receive data with 16-bit assembly[using masm].
for beginning I wrote this code to send a character to COM7 and listen to this port but no thing transmit. I tested monitor of this port with sending data using another software.
this is code:

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 100h
.data
.code
_start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov ah, 0           ;Initialize opcode
mov al, 11100011b   ;Parameter data.
mov dx, 6           ;COM7: port.
int 14h
again:
    mov  dx, 6           ;Select COM7:
    mov  al, 'm'        ;Character to transmit
    mov  ah, 1           ;Transmit opcode
    int  14h
    jmp again   
mov ah,1
int 21h
END _start
```

where is my wrong?

Comment: Are you sure about the init parameters? 8 data bits, 2 stop bits, no parity, and 600bps? Besides, you have an infinite loop AFAICS

Comment: I set it as come in [link](http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH13/CH13-3.html#HEADING3-7)

Comment: Play around with those parameters, they depend on your actual hardware. For starters, try reducing speed, maybe try just one stop bit, etc... change one parameter at a  time

Comment: I'm in doubt whether int 14h support coms up to 4 or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH13/CH13-3.html#HEADING3-1

> The IBM BIOS supports up to four different serial communications ports
>   (the hardware supports up to eight). In general, most PCs have one or
>   two serial ports (COM1: and COM2:) installed. Int 14h supports four
>   subfunctions- initialize, transmit a character, receive a character,
>   and status. For all four services, the serial port number (a value in
>   the range 0..3) is in the dx register (0=COM1:, 1=COM2:, etc.). Int
>   14h expects and returns other data in the al or ax register.

It doesn't support `COM7/COM6`.

Comment: thank you 0x90, I tried impossible thing! now I decide to use "advanced virtual com port". again I thank you!!!